# Create Marketing Cloud Portfolio item using data URI scheme

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

It doesn't appear that using a data URI scheme to add a portfolio object is supported. Can anyone confirm or let me know what's incorrect with the following SOAP-API call?

Request:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header/>
    <Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options/>
            <Objects xsi:type="Portfolio">
                <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Client>
                    <ID>xxxxxxx</ID>
                </Client>
                <CustomerKey />
                <Source>
                    <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <URN>data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIAQMAAACXljzdAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAA7ElEQVRYw+2XuxGEMAxE1+OAkBIohdLs0iiFEggJPNZJAu6O4YhPYrwBvxfJs9IKoKnJswYSzWMmWnt9XjyQiS/9DFDRGzofJFHp55GCEH72RRBXfyTf1mOTbN5J4vifrvojObqxxrs+NUjeCrTejECDhOupEF9rJSeH2CaICzuoRjl/P4S7kSYE/jZkRPJBMucLdF4DiX0PD2TiN5KxIn2az9loluzietTxobgg+0zk85eBnq47n01ybE/qdUkhS0RzG6iQbvRFJBvJIdn2EJ0kHoh6h7OxdGzw615lk3z+s1j5ux7DpKnpaXoB5td66RZyOkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=</URN>
                </Source>   
                <FileName>_qr-test1234.png</FileName>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:45537d01-7fd1-4b74-9cf0-bdc083c389a6</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:f62f1c0a-5b0d-4a9b-90b8-8d34cc590729</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-6d4545ed-36ce-4554-924b-995d56b1f701">
            <wsu:Created>2017-06-21T17:38:36Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-06-21T17:43:36Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Results>
            <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Invalid Source URN. Path: data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIAQMAAACXljzdAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAA7ElEQVRYw+2XuxGEMAxE1+OAkBIohdLs0iiFEggJPNZJAu6O4YhPYrwBvxfJs9IKoKnJswYSzWMmWnt9XjyQiS/9DFDRGzofJFHp55GCEH72RRBXfyTf1mOTbN5J4vifrvojObqxxrs+NUjeCrTejECDhOupEF9rJSeH2CaICzuoRjl/P4S7kSYE/jZkRPJBMucLdF4DiX0PD2TiN5KxIn2az9loluzietTxobgg+0zk85eBnq47n01ybE/qdUkhS0RzG6iQbvRFJBvJIdn2EJ0kHoh6h7OxdGzw615lk3z+s1j5ux7DpKnpaXoB5td66RZyOkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <ErrorCode>69008</ErrorCode>
            <NewID>0</NewID>
            <Object xsi:type="Portfolio">
               <Client>
                  <ID>xxxxxxx</ID>
               </Client>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey/>
               <Source>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <URN>data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADIAQMAAACXljzdAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAA7ElEQVRYw+2XuxGEMAxE1+OAkBIohdLs0iiFEggJPNZJAu6O4YhPYrwBvxfJs9IKoKnJswYSzWMmWnt9XjyQiS/9DFDRGzofJFHp55GCEH72RRBXfyTf1mOTbN5J4vifrvojObqxxrs+NUjeCrTejECDhOupEF9rJSeH2CaICzuoRjl/P4S7kSYE/jZkRPJBMucLdF4DiX0PD2TiN5KxIn2az9loluzietTxobgg+0zk85eBnq47n01ybE/qdUkhS0RzG6iQbvRFJBvJIdn2EJ0kHoh6h7OxdGzw615lk3z+s1j5ux7DpKnpaXoB5td66RZyOkwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=</URN>
               </Source>
               <FileName>_qr-test1234.png</FileName>
            </Object>
         </Results>
         <RequestID>182cced7-258f-468e-9854-532301406e96</RequestID>
         <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
      </CreateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a URL string in  instead of base64 encoded content.

```
<Source>
<ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
<ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
<URN>http://www.example.com/images/example.jpg</URN>
</Source>
```